# Insert rows returned by stored procedure into a different table - different databases and servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, data-migration

I have a local table in database `Test` like:

```
CREATE TABLE [SavedData]
(
    [RowID] INT NOT NULL , 
    [Category] INT NOT NULL , 
    [X] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [Y] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([RowID])
)
```

I have a procedure in remote database `LiveData` on a different server like `GetData(INT category)` which returns multiple rows `RowID, X, Y`.

My table is being used to capture data for local testing so I'm wondering if I can do this in one step rather than go via clunky CSV files or something? e.g. `Category` and the results of `EXEC GetData(Category)` are inserted into `SavedData` using some cross-DB query/script.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for DB queries if at all possible. I'm doing this migration manually to populate local test data, not from code in my application.

Specifically, I have two DB connections in VS:

[image]

DB 'Test' is in my localdb, DB 'LiveData' is the SQL2014 one.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but where is the actual code that reads and the code that writes?

Comment: @Steve I'm doing this migration manually to populate local test data, not from code. (added this to the Q)

Answer (score 2):

Yes since you already have a table that matches the result of your procedure you can do this quite easily.

```
insert SavedData
(
    Category
    , X
    , Y
)
exec MyRemoteServer.DatabaseName.SchemaName.ProcedureName
```

Comment: I can't get this syntax to work, I'm not sure how to qualify the remote DB. I updated my question, can you edit the answer specific to my example?

Comment: You need to have a linked server created in order to access the data remotely like this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Not come across that... perhaps you can expand an example in you answer. I'm assuming this must be done in a script coded explicitly, VS doesn't provide a GUI-friendly way? I'll play around with it in the meantime anyway :)

Comment: I did provide an example. Notice the 4 part naming? The first one is the linked server name. You need to create that. Or you can use the data migration tool (Tasks -> Import Data) in SSMS since it sounds like this is a one time thing.

Comment: I meant a full example including the server linkage in the script. I seem to have this figured out now but only after digging through that link you shared and several false attempts... a future viewer would benefit from seeing that in your example. Also... Tasks -> Import Data sounds like it would be a valid alternative answer.

Comment: I couldn't begin to script out your linked server. There are so many options and details that any example would only be a partial example. That is why I provided the link to MS. And since you specifically asked about using a stored procedure and storing it in a table I only mentioned import data wizard as an afterthought. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Well I say I got it working _except_ that my table has column `Category` which is an `IN` parameter to the stored proc, not something it returns. I can't see a way around that